# Error when extracting info with youtube_dl

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-dl

I'm currently making a program to transfer songs saved on my YT account into a Spotify playlist, and I am using youtube_dl to extract the meta data from the YT videos using the code below:

```
# use youtube_dl to collect the song name & artist name
        video = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL({}).extract_info(
            youtube_url, download=False)
        song_name = video["track"]
        artist = video["artist"]
```

When I was first made this project in March, the json that resulted from extract_info included the proper artist name, but now the artist, along with many other values (although not necessary for this task) are listed as None. Has anyone run into this issue? I'm considering a work around of not using the artist name to get the uri, but that would make it impossible to distinguish two songs with the same name. If anyone else has noticed this and has found a solution I'd love to hear it!

Comment: i think `youtube_dl` is extracting artist, track fields **only** from certain videos, particularly those that are uploaded by YT with copyright holders' permission, having description like "Provided to YouTube by ......" i tried your code with a video of this kind, and youtube_dl extracted the fields fine.

Comment: That's so strange. Can I ask what video you used? All of the videos I am trying to extract from are registered as "Music" by YouTube but still don't return the correct song info. Also, this is the playlist I used just in case I'm totally looking over something. https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLT6RFFUUdzx8HEANLbhHH4UO-M8E4Ue09

Comment: i checked the playlist you provided, besides 1st video that is blocked in my country, all rest are regular videos, not falling to the category i mentioned previously (description has that special format). i am adding an answer to provide logs too

Answer (score 0):

Here is the video I tried your code with: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QBxSQXbj6Go

And the code and output from your snippet below.

Script:

```
[http_offline@greenhat-32 LEARNING]$ cat tests2.py 
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import youtube_dl

# use youtube_dl to collect the song name & artist name

youtube_url = 'QBxSQXbj6Go'
video = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL({}).extract_info(youtube_url, download=False)
song_name = video["track"]
artist = video["artist"]

print(artist, ' - ', song_name)
[http_offline@greenhat-32 LEARNING]$
```

Output:

```
[http_offline@greenhat-32 LEARNING]$ ./tests2.py 
[youtube] QBxSQXbj6Go: Downloading webpage
[youtube] QBxSQXbj6Go: Downloading MPD manifest
REO Speedwagon  -  Keep Pushin'
[http_offline@greenhat-32 LEARNING]$
```

youtube-dl can't extract Artist, Release Date and other certain fields from any video, it has to be a video with the description format like the video I provided above.

PS. it won't help you, but they released a new youtube-dl version a few days ago, you might want to grab it.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the user-agent to Facebook's web crawler seems to solve this

```
youtube_dl.utils.std_headers['User-Agent'] = "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)"
```